# Is this boolean simplification allowed in terms of boolean algebra laws?

Tags: math, boolean, logic, boolean-logic, algebra

A.B + B' = (A+B').(B+B') = (A+B').1 = (A+B').
In k-maps, the result is the same, but is the simplification correct or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct. There are only four possible states for the combination of A and B. If this equality holds true for all four of these states in a Karnaugh map, then it's absolutely true.

[Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) is just a different way of obtaining the same result.

- A.B + B' = A.B' + (A+B') . (B+B') (distributivity of ∧ over ∨)
- B + B' = 1 (complementation law for ∨)
- (A+B') . 1 = A+B' (identity law for ∧)